# Operations in Python

Tags: python

My question is fairly basic yet might need a challenging solution.

Essentially, I have an arbitrary function which we will call some_function.

```
def some_function(n):
    for i in range(n):
           i+i
    r = 1
    r = r+1
```

And I want to count the number of operations took place in an arbitrary call to this function is executed (e.g. `some_function(5)`. there are 7 operations that took place).

How would one count the number of operations that took place within a function call? I cannot modify `some_function`.

Comment: what is an "operation"?  is `range(n)` an operation?  is `r+1`?  note that `pass` is the explicit _lack_ of an operation; it compiles to nothing.

Comment: I am just looking for a general measure of how many computations took place during a particular function call.

Comment: Do you need code to count this, or do you need to do it by hand? What exactly constitutes an operation is very vague, and it's hard to track a lot of things. You might be able to instrument the bytecode interpreter loop to count bytecode instructions executed, but that is probably way beyond the scope of your knowledge. Profiling your code with something like `cProfile` would give you useful data. Likely not the kind you're looking for, but probably more useful than the kind you're looking for.

Comment: I am looking for some code snippet to calculate this automatically.

Comment: but _why_?  what problem are you trying to solve?  the thing you're asking for is very poorly-defined.

Comment: Counting the no. of bytecode or machine-code operations does not give you an idea of the "complexity" of your algorithm (See: [Big O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)) -- What does is the "complexity" (*hence the name*) -- In your example this is ``O(n)``.

Comment: Right, I understand this - but out of interest, I still am curious in finding the number of 'Python' operations per function call.

Comment: The answer is always going to be `n+2` isn't it ? Further, the two instructions at the end could be replaced with a simple `r = 2`

Comment: You mean the no. of bytecode instructions?

Comment: there is no such thing as an "operation".  `r = r+1` executes at least three instructions, and that's only on CPython specifically.  you might as well be asking how many operations happen when you turn on a microwave.

Comment: @JamesMills Either-or would work. I am just interested in a general measure of operations that took place such that I can compare them. Time works, but it is also dependent on the computer.

Comment: You should read the documentation on the built-in [profilers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html). It sounds like ``cProfile`` is going to be the closest to doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: @aruisdante Bingo - that looks like what I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're really after what others already told you - the big O notation.

But if you really want to know the actual number of instructions executed you can use this on linux:

```
perf stat -e instructions:u python yourscript.py
```

Which will output:

> Performance counter stats for 'python yourscript.py':
>
> ```
>     22,260,577 instructions:u           
>
>    0.014450363 seconds time elapsed
> ```

Note though that it includes all the instructions for executing python itself. So you'd have to find your own reference.

Answer (score 1):

Using [byteplay](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/byteplay):

**Example:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


from byteplay import Code


def some_function(n):
    for i in range(n):
        i + i
    r = 1
    r = r + 1


def no_of_bytecode_instructions(f):
    code = Code.from_code(f.func_code)
    return len(code.code)


print(no_of_bytecode_instructions(some_function))
```

**Output:**

```
$ python -i foo.py
28
>>>
```

**NB:**

- This still gives you no idea how complex `f` is here.
- "Number of Instructions" != "Algorithm Complexity" (*not by itself*)
- See: [Big O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

> Algorithm complexity is a measure of the no. of instructions executed
>   relative to the size of your input data set(s).

*Some naive examples of "complexity" and [Big O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation):*

```
def func1(just_a_list):
    """O(n)"""

    for i in just_a_list:
        ...

def func2(list_of_lists):
    """O(n^2)"""

    for i in list_of_lsits:
        for j in i:
            ...

def func3(a_dict, a_key):
    """O(1)"""

    return a_dict[a_key]
```

Comment: Nice find! I'll have a look at this. Plus, why should it not give me an idea of the complexity of f?

Comment: Because "number of instructions" != "algorithm complexity".

Comment: Pardon my naiveness, however is this a law that I haven't of heard yet?

Comment: While this is a nice tool, "number of instructions in the function" and "number of instructions executed" are very different metrics. We're after a measure closer to runtime, not code length.

Comment: Algorithm complexity refers to how many instructions will be executed _relative to the size of your input set_. It's a very useful and important measure. Read his link on Big O.